# BroadcastReceiver with Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED getting called multiple times

Tags: java, android

I have registered `BroadcastReceiver` in Service like this

```
if(isReceiverReg){
isReceiverReg = false;

 registerReceiver(batteryTrackingReceiver, new 
 IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)); }
```

while running the app `onReceive` method is fired multiple times.... is there any walk around method

Comment: post appropriate code here

Comment: Hi SIMZ, welcome to StackOverflow. When asking questions, it can be helpful to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In this case, adding a MVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be useful in understanding what is happening.

Comment: post your service class